# Invalid parameter 'logisticregression' for estimator Pipeline. GridSearchCV and ColumnTransformer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm trying to perform a GridSearchCV including a pipeline.
I want to impute and standardize the numerical variables.
And just impute the categorical ones.

I've tried to do it like this:

```
numeric_cols = X_train.select_dtypes(include=['float64', 'int']).columns.to_list()
cat_cols = X_train.select_dtypes(include=['object', 'category']).columns.to_list()

numeric_transformer = Pipeline( steps=[ ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
   ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer( transformers=[
        ('numeric', numeric_transformer, numeric_cols),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, cat_cols)],
        remainder='passthrough',verbose_feature_names_out = False).set_output(transform="pandas")

completo = Pipeline( steps=[("preprocessor", preprocessor), ("classifier", 
   LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', penalty='l2', max_iter=100, class_weight='balanced'))] )

params = dict(logisticregression__C=np.logspace(-4, 16,21,  base=1.5)) 

grid_search_lr2 = GridSearchCV(completo, params, scoring='roc_auc')  

results_lr2 = grid_search_lr2.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But it produces an error:

> Invalid parameter 'logisticregression' for estimator
> Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor',
> ColumnTransformer(remainder='passthrough',...

What is the proper way to do it?
It may not need to use ColumnTransformer. Or it may be a problem with the way I'm introducing the LogisticRegression.

I don't have any problem when I use a simpler pipeline (the same for all data types) and make_pipeline.

Comment: Your related question should be a _new_ question.  See the close reason "needs focus" and [related notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417486/10495893).

Comment: Imputing: *[Pandas: Imputing missing values to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472706/pandas-imputing-missing-values-to-data-frame)*

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the name of your hyperparameter in the definition of `params`: `logisticregression__C` refers to the `C` parameter of the pipeline step *named* `logisticregression`. But there is no such step, because you've named the step `classifier` in the pipeline.

The convenience function `make_pipeline` creates a pipeline whose step names are just lowercased versions of the class names, which is why it worked then.